# Applying css on a imported react component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a UserPreview component which have other components( avatar, bio, followstats). When, I am trying to style these components, nothing happens. I tried inline styling as well. But, Styling on a normal div is working perfectly fine. I have no idea why its happening.

```
import React from "react";

import Avatar from "../../Atoms/Avatar";
import Bio from "../../Atoms/Bio";
import FollowStats from "../../Atoms/FollowStats";

import Profile from "../../Assets/images/profile.jpg";

import useStyles from "./style";

const UserPreview = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Avatar
        size="large"
        image={Profile}
        name="Aman"
        username="dev_aman7"
        className={classes.avatar}
        style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}
      />
      <Bio value="This is Bio" className={classes.bio} />
      <div className={classes.edit}>Edit Profile</div>
      <FollowStats followers={20} following={30} className={classes.follow} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserPreview;
```

Styles

```
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    maxWidth: "20rem",
    flexDirection: "column",
    paddingTop: "1rem",
  },
  avatar: {
    padding: "5rem",
    border: "1px solid black",
  },
  bio: {
    marginTop: "1rem",
  },
  edit: {
    color: theme.palette.blue,
    fontSize: theme.f5,

    margin: "auto",
    marginTop: ".5rem",
  },
  follow: {
    margin: "1.5rem",
    width: "100%",
  },
}));

export default useStyles;
```

Material ui is used as design library

Avatar.jsx

```js
import React from "react";

import ClassNames from "classnames";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import useStyles from "./style";

const Avatar = ({ image, size, name, username }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const container = ClassNames(
    { [classes.root_small]: size === "small" },
    { [classes.root_large]: size !== "small" }
  );

  const usernameClass = ClassNames(classes.username, {
    [classes.grey]: size === "small",
  });

  const imgClass = ClassNames(
    classes.img,
    { [classes.img_small]: size === "small" },
    { [classes.img_large]: size !== "small" }
  );

  return (
    <div className={container}>
      <div>
        <img src={image} alt="Profile_image" className={imgClass} />
      </div>
      {size === "small" ? null : <div className={classes.name}>{name}</div>}
      <div className={usernameClass}>@{username}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

Avatar.defaultProps = { name: "" };

Avatar.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Avatar;
```

```css
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root_small: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  root_large: {
    maxWidth: "20rem",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  img: {
    borderRadius: "50%",
  },
  img_small: {
    height: "2.5rem",
    width: "2.5rem",
    marginRight: "1rem",
  },
  img_large: { width: "4.5rem", height: "4.5rem" },
  name: {
    fontSize: theme.f2,
    fontWeight: theme.bold6,
    marginTop: "0.5rem",
    color: theme.palette.grey,
  },
  username: {
    fontSize: theme.f4,
    color: theme.palette.pinkGrey,
  },
  grey: {
    color: theme.palette.grey,
  },
}));

export default useStyles;
```

Comment: can you share your other components as well?

Comment: I have added avatar component for reference

Comment: add `!iumportant` for styles

Comment: You are passing the class name to the avatar component, but you also need to extract it from the props in the avatar and pass it to container as well. Or it will be discarded.

Comment: Thank you @Domino987 , Your point actually makes sense.